# Jquery Colorbox issue with opening inline div when click is associated to dynamically created div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, inline, colorbox

I am using colorbox and it is working as expected on buttons created in html.
I need the colorbox trigger to be on a dynamically created div but it results in the #cboxLoadedContent not loading the inline content.
if i use a generic div i created within the HTML the inline opens and shows the content.

the following is the jquery i am using to pop up the box only difference would be the 'trigger' div.

```
    $(".thingsObjects").colorbox({  
            inline:true,  
            width:$(document).width(),   
            height:$(document).height(),   
            onLoad:function() {  
            $('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden'); // page scrollbars off  
            },   
            onClosed:function() {  
            $('html, body').css('overflow', ''); // page scrollbars on  
            }  
    });
```

is there an issue with using dynamic div's?
any pointers would be appreciated
cheers

As requested by punitdam thanks for the reply, the H was accidently added when I pasted it into SOverflow.
The following function is called when the div is added. The colorbox opens and covers the window but is empty unlike the .inline which was added from the beginning.

```
    function createPopUp(){
    $(".thingsObjects").colorbox({
        inline:true,
        width:$(document).width(), 
        height:$(document).height(), 
        onLoad:function() {
            $('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden'); // page scrollbars off
        }, 
        onClosed:function() {
            $('html, body').css('overflow', ''); // page scrollbars on
        }
    });        

    $(".inline").colorbox({
        inline:true,
        width:$(document).width(), 
        height:$(document).height(), 
        onLoad:function() {
            $('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden'); // page scrollbars off
        }, 
        onClosed:function() {
            $('html, body').css('overflow', ''); // page scrollbars on
        }
    });
    $('.popClose').bind('click', function(){
        $.colorbox.close();
    });
}
```

the dynamic creation of the div's is a little convulted but the main code is as follows

```
    for (var i = thingAmount; i > 0; i -= 1) { // cycle through and create new thing div
        $(".thingsObjects").prepend('<div class="thingsFront' + ' ' + thingsOptions[nextIndex] + (i) + ' ' + nextMenu +'"></div>');
        var currentThing = ".Shoes" + (i) ; // var to hold changeable div
            $(currentThing).css({'background-image':'url(' + SHOESImageList[i-1] + ')', 'opacity':1 })
                .waitForImages(function() {
            }, function(loaded, count, success) {              
                var img = new Image;
                img.src = $(currentThing).css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
                changePropertiesOfThumbs(howManyMade);
                howManyMade ++;
                if (howManyMade >= thingAmount){
                    repopulationFinished();
                }                        
            }, $.noop, true);           
    }
```

Comment: changed the prepend to address issue stated below i.e. that href="#inline_content" missing from dynamic div.  I also tried to add the class cboxElement to the div still to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like attribute inline you have misspelled as Hinline. 
It would be great if you can add code for dynamic div creation also. You need to call colorbox method after Div is added to DOM.

Comment: Thanks punitdam, as requested added the code used to create dynamic div's

Answer (score 0):

Once i created a barebones test i discovered i forgot to prepend the new div with href="#inline_content". It works in this test i created below but not in my main site. I noticed that for each colorbox call that a new class cboxElement is added to the div I am guessing this is the issue as in my code above cboxElement is not added to my dynamic div's.

Here is a working test may come into use for somebody it doesnt fix my situation but may others.

Thanks again for you time punitdam.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>Colorbox Inline</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/core/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorbox.css" />
    <script src="scripts/core/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>



    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".inline").colorbox({
                inline:true,
                width:$(document).width(), 
                height:$(document).height(), 
                onLoad:function() {
                    $('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden'); // page scrollbars off
                }, 
                onClosed:function() {
                    $('html, body').css('overflow', ''); // page scrollbars on
                }
            });

            $('.popClose').bind('click', function(){
                $.colorbox.close();
            });

        $(".testBtn").prepend('<div class="dynamicTest" href="#inline_content">NEW TEST BTN</div>');

            $(".dynamicTest").colorbox({
                inline:true,
                width:$(document).width(), 
                height:$(document).height(), 
                onLoad:function() {
                    $('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden'); // page scrollbars off
                }, 
                onClosed:function() {
                    $('html, body').css('overflow', ''); // page scrollbars on
                }
            });                
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p><a class='inline' href="#inline_content">Inline HTML</a></p>

    <div class="testBtn">TESTER</div>

    <div style='display:none'>
        <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
            <div id="pop">
                TEST CONTENT !
            </div> 
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```